# Python RE: How do I split by 0 or more times for literal *

Tags: python, python-re

I am using Python re.

My example below is simplified but basically I have a string of numbers with the last number sometimes having 0, 1 or more *.

2.43    9.06

1.233   3.6*

3.233   9.00**

Basically I want to extract the last number without the *. I tried to re.split by *

```
text = 2.43    9.06
text_list=re.split('\**',str(text))
OR
text_list=re.split('\*{0,}',str(text))
```

**Result: Split everything (all digits) into a list**

When I tried this, it works if my last number has * but doesn't work if there is no *

```
text_list=re.split('\*+',str(text))
```

1. So basically I need to split by * if it is present, otherwise no splitting takes place.
2. Next, I need to extract the last number [which already has its * (if present) removed]

Thank you

Comment: It's easier to understand your issue if you provide input and output pairs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the need to split on `*`. Why not `s.rstrip("*").split(" ")[-1]`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand but I would do something like that:

```py
text = '3.233 9.00**'
last_number_with_starts = text.split(' ')[-1]   # '9.00**'
last_number = last_number_with_starts.split('*')[0]   # '9.00'
last_digit = last_number[-1]  # '0'
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I haven't been clear. If text = '3.233 9.00**', I want to extract 9.00 - the last NUMBER. But sometimes, my last number, don't have any * at the back, so if I use a simple split it may not work. I solved by using restrip. Thanks

Comment: Actually using a simple `split` will still work even if there is no `"*"` : `'9.00'.split('*')` with return `['9.00']` . So in your case you can use the variable `last_number` of my example. Anyway, good for you if you managed to make it work.